# Extra code is printed when editing List with specific index

Tags: c#, php, .net

I'm creating a simple C# program that automates editing different parts for a specific PHP file (for my work). But I have a problem. I'm working with multiple PHP files, all in different sub-folders, but with the same layout.

The program has access to all folders, and edits all the files at once. It stores the contents of each file in a `List<string>`. The main purpose of the program is to update a single string in each file, and then save the file. When this is done, I want `Console` to print out the single updated string in each file, and the path of the file with it. Here is this specific part of the program:

```c#
foreach(string item in paths)
            {
                if(File.Exists(item) == false) // checks if file exists
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Error!");
                    Console.WriteLine("File named " + Path.GetFileName(item) + " was not found.");
                    Console.WriteLine("Please confirm that you selected the right file.");
                }
                else
                {
                    List<string> filecontents = File.ReadAllLines(item).ToList<string>();

                    for(int i = 0; i < filecontents.Count; i++)
                    {
                        if(!filecontents[i].StartsWith(@"//")) // checks to find right string to update
                        {
                            if(filecontents[i].Contains("http://") && !filecontents[i].Contains("https://")) // checks to find right string to update
                            {
                                string tempsubstring = filecontents[i].Substring(filecontents[i].IndexOf("http://") + 7, filecontents[i].IndexOf(@"/uadmin/gate.php") - (filecontents[i].IndexOf("http://")) - 7);
                                // extremely long code to extract substring where domainname needs to be filled in

                                filecontents[i].Replace(tempsubstring, domainname); // replace substring with own string

                                Console.WriteLine(filecontents[i]);
                                Console.WriteLine("Found at " + Path.GetFileName(Directory.GetParent(item).ToString())); // only prints name of parent file
                                Console.WriteLine();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

This code seems fine to me at first, until I look at the outcome:

```
$real_home="http://test123/uadmin/gate.php";
Found at (path of parent folder)

System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]$real_home="http://test123/uadmin/gate.php";
Found at (path of parent folder)

System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]$real_home="http://test123/uadmin/gate.php";
Found at (path of parent folder)

System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]$real_home="http://test123/uadmin/gate.php";
Found at *path of parent folder*

System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]$real_home="http://test123/uadmin/gate.php";
Found at (path of parent folder)

System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]$real_home="http://test123/uadmin/gate.php";
Found at (path of parent folder)

System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]$real_home="http://test123/uadmin/gate.php";
Found at (path of parent folder)

System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]$real_home="http://test123/uadmin/gate.php";
Found at (path of parent folder)

System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]
```

The program is working here, since I put "test123" in as the variable `domainname`. But ofcourse this string:

```
System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]
```

Does not belong there.

Now, here's my question. Is this only when I print out that specific string from `filecontents`? or is it also stored in the list like that? Also, does anybody know why this happens, and how to remove it?

P.S: Converting the list to an array before printing also did not help.

Comment: it means it's a `list`, you need to loop over it, any chance you can provide an example for the dummy PHP file?

Comment: This usually happens if you call `ToString()` on a `List` type object, or similar. Have you inspected the `tempsubstring` variable to see if that type string is making its way in there? And the file contents, have you verified that yourself?